# How to install MS office on Windows azure server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I host my website in windows azure server using custom website and I need MS office installation on this server. Can Anyone help me how to install MS office on my windows azure server.

I have created a Web Site not a virtual machine.

Answer (score 4):

You simply can't do that with Web Sites.  You're best option is to use a VM.